# How to change size, color of tab headings of twitter bootstrap uib-tab

Tags: html, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i am trying to change the color of tab, make size smaller so i can fit all tabs in one row

```
     <uib-tabset type="tabs" >
        <uib-tab heading="Event Information" > </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="Event Information" > </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="Event Information" > </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="Event Information" > </uib-tab>
     </uib-tabset>
```

how can i change the css

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the templates that the directive is actually using and modify the classes being used there (or use your own ones), they are on the **/template/tabs** folder

Comment: /template/tabs folder under bootstrap folder? or any other? i can't find it

Comment: You are using angular-ui right? I saw the path using the official repository: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template/tabs